# Galois group of splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb F_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I want to compute the Galois group of splitting field of $p(x) =x^3-2$ over $\mathbb F_7$.

I can see that $\sqrt [3]{2}$, $\zeta_3\sqrt [3]{2}$, and $\zeta_3 ^2 \sqrt [3]{2}$ are the roots of $p(x)$ over $\mathbb Q$.

But I am not sure if this holds over $\mathbb F_7$ or if $p(x)$ is even irreducible, as I can't use Eisenstein, for example.

I've read that any extension of finite fields has cyclic Galois group, so that we can generate the group in this case by the Frobenius $x \mapsto x^7$. But I can't see why this is true, at least in this example.

Comment: Since the polynomial is cubic, is irreducible iff it has no root.

Comment: You can't use Eisenstein, but you check that it has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_7$. And a cubic polynomial without roots is irreducible.

Comment: In $\Bbb{F}_7$ the element $2$ can serve in the role of $\zeta_3$, because it is of order three :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick check shows that $x^3-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_7$ (it doesn't have a root).  A basis for the splitting field over $\Bbb{F}_7$ is given by $a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2$ where $\alpha^3=2$.  A count shows we have 343 elements.  The automorphism $x\mapsto x^7$ sends $\alpha$ to $\alpha^7 = 4\alpha$ and since $4^3 \equiv 1\bmod 7$ we see that $\alpha$ is mapped to another root of $x^3-2$.  Furthermore it's clear since $4^3 \equiv 1\bmod 7$ the automorphism has order $3$.

Comment: Does it not matter which root $\alpha$ is exactly? Also, I guess the Galois group is $\mathbb Z_3$? Finally, is it true in general that a finite Galois extension is primitive, so that we know the splitting field is of degree $3$ in this case?

Comment: Algebraically the roots are indistinguishable.  Over the reals you can say things like the real cube of $2$ or the positive square root of $2$, and even over the $p$-adics you can impose congruence conditions, but you don't have anything like that here.  Yes the Galois group is isomorphic to $C_3$.

Comment: And to your last question the primitive element theorem say that every finite separable extension of fields has a primitive element, so yes since Galois = normal and separable, a finite Galois extension is simple.

Comment: Another way of reaching the same conclusion is to observe that $\alpha$ is of multiplicative order nine. As $q=7^3$ is the lowest power of seven such that $9\mid q-1$, it follows that $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{7^3}\setminus\Bbb{F}_7$. No matter, this is a fine answer.